# Is there a 64 bit binary version of ujson or cjson for Python 2.7

Tags: python, windows, json

I am looking for a Windows 64bit binary version of uJson or cJson (preferably the former). Does it exist? If so, could you please post a link?

Or am I missing something and there is some way of installing it on a 64 bit Windows system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ has windows binaries (32 and 64 bit) for many packages.  It looks like the "base" package there (at the bottom of the page) contains ujson.